# phonegap android app crashing due to low memory on opening camera

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an android phonegap app using phonegap v1.3.0 
 My app has a button which when clicks launches the camera using the phonegap api, when returns the photo path when the user captures the image. 
 But what is happening is that the app crashes before the camera returns, so when the camera returns, the app is restarted. So I dont get the image which was captured. 
 On checking the logs I see that the kernal sends **sigkill** to my app after the camera is launched. 
 A point to note is that when I kill all the running apps and then start my app and take a picture it returns normally without the app crashing. 

 This issue is similar to https://github.com/callback/phonegap/issues/5 
Please tell me what could be going wrong?

Here are the logs - https://github.com/ghostCoder/Logs/blob/master/e2o.mobile-logs.txt  
 the name of my app is e2o.mobile

Here are the contents of my manifest.xml--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="xyz.test"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"/>  



<application android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name=".Home" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction">


</activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: `im developing an android phonegap app` there's your problem. Using a third party framework to create apps leaves you completely at the mercy of the stability of that framework. I realise that its useful because you can build for many platforms, but I would always advise against anything like this. The features and functionality of each platform vary so much its almost never a good idea to use one codebase. In this case, unless you're doing something really wrong then its probably a quirk of phonegap's. I would submit a bug report with them and wait to see the outcome.

Comment: Actually it is probably being caused by a crappy implementation of the Camera Intent by Sony. Lots of Android manufactures add "bloatware" to the Android distro and that tends to mess things up. I love Android and I love developing for it but these types of issues keep me up at night. Literally! One PhoneGap user who had a similar issue had his user install a third party camera app and use that to take pictures and BOOM! the problem went away. I'm trying not to use the 13 letter F word here.

Comment: i am trying to design a workaround for this issue, apart from the using the third party camera app soln. The app is killed(after the camera is launched), and restarted when the camera returns. After it reboots it can see if it had crashed during file capture and retrieve the image captured. I had written a phonegap plugin to do this but i was facing an issue. can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910443/android-phonegap-app-unable-to-retrieve-an-image-taken-by-the-camera-using-my

Comment: @SimonMacDonald I installed camera apps like Camera 360, lightbox and tried taking pictures with it, thru the app instead of using the default camera. But the app still crashes post camera launch. so my issue still remains unsolved. :(
can u please suggest something else?

Comment: @ghostCoder what is the min sdk value in your manifest.xml? What SDK do you build against? What do the activity lines look like in your manifest.xml?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald edited my question to add the contents of AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: really sry couldnt reply to u over the weekend. im building against Android version 2.3.3 (API 10)

Comment: That's okay @ghostCoder I do have a life. You should always build your app against the latest version of Android, 4.0 in this case and let it handle backward compatibility. You've specified your app will work from level 7 and up which is good. The root cause of the issue is out of memory when passing around the bitmap. Try reducing the width and height of the picture to reduce memory.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the quality parameter from 50 to 30 stopped the camera API from crashing the app on my HTC Evo.

Comment: took that to 10, no diff in behavior  :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce image size with targetWidth and targetHeight.
Use DestinationType FILE_URI.

Comment: reducing dimensions does nothing. same issue. :(